# Way to use Entity Framework with Classic Asp

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp-classic, vb6

In my company, we have almost all the systems running on classic asp with the logic layer in dlls made by vb6. We use sql server and it's used via stored procedures.

Recently I found how easy is to connect to a procedure using entity framework, and we are trying to avoid the usage of vb6, and for tests purposes, i create a project in .net similar to the ones we use in vb6 with entity framework connecting to the procedure, and generating the tbl and using regAsm to register the dll, I could use it in the classic asp, but when i try to access the method that access the procedure, it gives me the return:

No connection string named 'xEntities' could be found in the application config file.

Where xEntities is the name of my context.

We can't migrate everything to the asp.net because of the time, but it will be very good if we stop using vb6.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the constructor `new xEntities(string connectionString)`. The default constructor searches the app.config (which doesn't exist for your vb6 app) for a connection string named xEntities.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a web.config file with the appropriate Entity Framework sections in your web site folder?  It is possible to have a web.config in a folder with an ASP Classic web site.